# insert multiple rows from table to another with a value

Tags: mysql

I want to insert multiple rows from table to another table, the table I want to get rows from, I only want twho columns, but in the distination table I have three columns, the two first columns in the source table will be affected to the two columns in the distination table, and the third clumn in the distination table will be affected by a value.

Here is the values I want to select from the source table :

```
SELECT codeArt, qte FROM LigneBonEntrée
            WHERE numBon = NEW.num
```

and in the distination folder I have an insert as :

```
INSERT INTO LigneInterventaire(codeArt, qteInv, numInv) 
            VALUES (NEW.codeArt, NEW.qte, LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

If I tried this :

```
INSERT INTO LigneInterventaire(codeArt, qteInv, numInv) 
SELECT codeArt, qte FROM LigneBonEntrée
WHERE numBon = NEW.num
```

I'll need to insert the value `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

How can I do that ?

## EDIT:

What I'm really trying to do is that I have a trigger on a table when this trigger is fired,  I want to insert to another table which called Inventaire the current date, and of course the inserted primary key will be the value of `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, then I want to use this `LAST_INSERT_ID()` for the following query :

```
INSERT INTO LigneInterventaire(codeArt, qteInv, numInv) 
            SELECT codeArt, qte FROM LigneBonEntrée
            WHERE numBon = NEW.num;
```

the value of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will be affected to the column `numInv`.

and the is the trigger I'm using:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `accepterLivraion` BEFORE UPDATE ON `BonEntrée`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE id INTEGER;
    IF NEW.etat = 'Accepté' THEN
        IF verifierLivraison(OLD.num) = FALSE THEN
            SIGNAL sqlstate '45001' set message_text = "La livraison n'a pas respectée les termes de la commande de sortie.";
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO Inventaire(`date`) VALUES (DATE(NOW());
            SET id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
            INSERT INTO LigneInterventaire(codeArt, qteInv, numInv) 
            SELECT codeArt, qte FROM LigneBonEntrée
            WHERE numBon = NEW.num;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You can't do as you ask.  I'm not even sure I can tell precisely what you are asking though or why you would do it.  You could just add `LAST_INSERT_ID()` into the `SELECT` as another field, but it would (I expect) have 1 value for all rows imported equating to the ID of the preceeding `INSERT` on the connection.  This is verified in this SQLFiddle example : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0aed5/1

Comment: @Simonatmso.net What about if I affected the value of LAST_INSERT_ID() to some variable before  and then I used this variable instead of LAST_INSERT_ID()

Comment: I don't know because I don't know what ID you are expecting to be returned by LAST_INSERT_ID().  If you are wanting it to be the ID from the previous insert from that `INSERT ... SELECT` then that is not possible.  What precisely are you trying to achieve here?  Please provide more details / sample datasets to illustrate your point.  It feels like you are trying to reinvent the wheel

Comment: @Simonatmso.net please see the modification I've made

Comment: Check the answer from @peterm below as it looks to do what you request.

Comment: @AimadMajdou Why did you swapped two lines `SET id=...` and `INSERT INTO Inventaire...` in edit2??? They were in correct order before. First you insert a row and then you read the auto_incremented value.

Comment: @peterm sorry, I didn't paid attention  ( Lack of sleep :( )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you already have your value in a variable `id`. Therefore just change

```
SELECT codeArt, qte FROM LigneBonEntrée
```

to

```
SELECT codeArt, qte, id FROM LigneBonEntrée
                     ^^
```

If your table `LigneBonEntrée` has a column `id` then change the name of your variable to which you assign `LAST_INSERT_ID()` or use an alias for table.